# Issue in clearing setInterval when a condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm working with the YouTube iFrame API to embed multiple videos. I have an interval set to get the current time of the video and close the player once this has been hit. When this condition has been met, I trigger a click on a close icon which should handle clearing the interval and other functionality.

It works when I close the video *before* the video has ended. However when I trigger the same functionality when the above condition has been met the interval never clears/seems to be called again.

Code:

```
// Call on the YouTube iFrame API.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var scrubberUpdate;

// Setup our player.
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    ytPlayer = new YT.Player(ytPlayerTarget, {
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {
          'autohide': 1,
          'autoplay': 1,
          'cc_load_policy': 0,
          'controls': 1,
          'disablekb': 0,
          'end': 0,
          'wmode': 'transparent',
          'fs': 1,
          'loop': 0,
          'html5': 1,
          'playsinline': 1,
          'rel': 0,
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
};

function closeFunc() {
    clearInterval(scrubberUpdate);
    ytPlayer.pauseVideo();
    ytPlayerCloseBtn.add(ytPlayerContainer).hide();
    ytPlayerWrapper.removeClass('playing').fadeOut();
}

function closeThePlayerOverlay() {
    ytPlayerCloseBtn.on('click', function() {
        closeFunc();
    });
}

function scrubberWidthCalc() {
    var ytPlayerDuration = ytPlayer.getDuration();
    var ytPlayerCustomEndTime = ytPlayerDuration - 0.2;
    var ytPlayerCurrentTime = ytPlayer.getCurrentTime();
    ytPlayerScrubber.css({
      'width': (ytPlayerCurrentTime / ytPlayerDuration) * 100 + '%'
    });
    if (ytPlayerCurrentTime > ytPlayerCustomEndTime) {
      ytPlayerCloseBtn.trigger('click');
    }
}

function scrubberWidth() {
    // console.log('scrubberUpdate');
    scrubberUpdate = setInterval(function() {
        scrubberWidthCalc();
    }, 10);
}

function loadVideo(theSource) {
    ytPlayer.loadVideoById(theSource, 0, 'default');
    ytPlayer.playVideo();
    scrubberWidth();
}

function triggerVideoPlayback() {
    ytPlayerTrigger.on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var theSource = $this.data('yt-dynamic-src');
        handleInline($this);
        if (ytPlayerWrapper.hasClass('playing')) {
          ytPlayer.pauseVideo();
          loadVideo(theSource);
        } else {
          openThePlayerOverlay();
          loadVideo(theSource);
        }
      });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
    playPauseFun();
    closeThePlayerOverlay();
    handleFullscreen();
    triggerVideoPlayback();
}
```

When I click '`ytPlayerCloseBtn`' while the video is playing/paused, it works fine and clears the interval.

When this click is triggered by the condition (`if (ytPlayerCurrentTime > ytPlayerCustomEndTime)...`) it does not clear the interval. My console log continues to run.

I've tried many variations on this but cannot see why the clearInterval does not work for this condition!

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: @Luca it's the relevant part of the code, however I will update my question with further pieces of code.

Comment: We'll need to see how these functions are called. For instance `closeThePlayerOverlay` just adds the handler for the click event to a particular element, so it doesn't make any changes to the UI...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've added further code!

Comment: Where are you declaring the `scrubberUpdate` variable?

Comment: @bastos.sergio this is declared just below the API call, I will update my code.

Comment: Why this line: `ytPlayerCloseBtn.trigger('click');`? Since the `click` handler only does one thing (call `closeFunc`) why not just call `closeFunc` instead of trying to "simulate" a click?